# Can I create a RAID-1 using Intel RTST on existing FIlesystem?

Tags: raid, raid1

I am installing ubuntu on a fileserver having existing data.
The server has 2X4TB disks in RAID-1 configuration usint Intel RTST. And Because the one is failing (the RAID-1 is degraded) I disassembled the RAID-1 configuration (using Intel RTST).

Also, my new Setup is using an SSD in order to install the ubuntu OS and then use the hard disk in RAID-1 configuration for data storage. Once I get my disk I will re-setup the RAID-1 array using Intel RTST. But until then I will need to make a temporary setup with a single disk.

So once I get my disk, can I use Intel RTST controller in order to recreate the RAID-1 without losing any data? I will need to format the disk that previously was in the RAID-1 configuration, so I can store the data in it.

Comment: RTST is considered 'fake RAID' in professional circles, one reason being that it struggles with more complex requests such as this, certainly more expensive RAID controllers allow for (slow) migration from one RAID level to another. I do think you probably need to wipe and rebuild sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm not familiar with Intel RTST, it's generally not possible to change a RAID configuration and retain the data on the disks. RAID1 is however somewhat an exception, since it's just a mirrored pair, so it might be possible. However, what you're suggesting is essentially a rebuild of a RAID1 pair, which puts a huge strain on the now only functioning drive, since all data essentially gets read from the drive in one go.

Depending on what drive you have, with that size of drives, you're more or less guaranteed an Unrecoverable Read Error (URE), aka. a block that can't be read on the drive.

As such, and always when changing drive configurations, your first step should be to ensure you have a good backup of the data before continuing.

Comment: Yeap I did my backup.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this in BIOS. Here are some instructions for Windows (if someone faced same question for Win). I assume there an alternative for Linux too:

- You have to boot into Windows,
- install Intel Rapid Storage Technology
- It would allow to create RAID from existing a volume.

https://bghints.blogspot.com/2016/07/intel-raid-create-mirror-raid-from.html